# How to loop through list of variables varying on hostname

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

So what I'm trying to do is have variables in a seperate file like so:

```
Pretend_server: "1.1.1.1"
Real_server: "8.8.8.8"
Bigdog_server: "139.130.4.5"
```

Call them:

```
vars:
  favcolor: blue
vars_files:
- ./external_vars.yml
```

and then to netcat from inventory_hostname + _server

```
  tasks:
  - name: Netcat
    shell: "nc -vz {{ inventory_hostname + '_server' }} 443"
    timeout: 5 
    register: netcat_results
```

So when the script ran on an inventory item with the hostname "Bigdog" it would append _server to the variable and reference the variable in the external variable file.

however it's doing this in output:

```
fatal: [cloudguru1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "nc -vz Bigdog_server 443"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need,

```
tasks:
  - name: Netcat
    shell: "nc -vz {{ vars[inventory_hostname + '_server'] }} 443"
    timeout: 5 
    register: netcat_results
```